# How to convert array of object keys into integers (select keys only) , JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got this array of objects :

```js
  [
{nutrient: "Energy", per100: "449kcal", per35: "157kcal", id: 6}
 {nutrient: "Fat", per100: "24.4g", per35: "8.6g", id: 1}
 {nutrient: "Saturated fat", per100: "4.5g", per35: "1.6g", id: 2}
 {nutrient: "Monounsaturated fat", per100: "13.6g", per35: "4.8g", id: 3}
]
```

I need to turn the per100 and per35 strings into Integers, but unsure how. Heres how I would approach it; first i'll use a regex or something else to delete any letters so im left with the strings "100" and "35" then from there its tricky.

I feel like I could just do this:

```js
  const newData = arr.forEach((d) => {
     console.log(parseInt(Object.keys))
     
    })

if I were to log out the keys only, i get this:

   ["nutrient", "per100", "per35", "id"]
    ["nutrient", "per100", "per35", "id"]
        ["nutrient", "per100", "per35", "id"]
        ["nutrient", "per100", "per35", "id"]
```

any ideas??

Comment: Given that `per100: "24.4g"` as a number is a decimal number, not an integer, are you sure you want integers? Also, you added a runnable snippet to your post, but you didn't put runnable code in it, so please remember to properly format your post and fix that.

Comment: hi, yes I only want the key to be an integer

Comment: Why? It feels like you're asking about how to implement your solution to some problem, without telling us what _that_ problem is, so: what are you actually doing that you think requires converting object keys from named keys to plain numbers?

Comment: because I need to apply a condition to those keys to first test if they're bigger than 100.

Comment: Then please update your post to explain that, because you're showing data that only has per100 and per35, meaning that based on what you're telling people, there is nothing over 100. Remember to [following the posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask). And please take out that runnable snippet code from your post, or edit to actually _be_ a runnable snippet.

Comment: please add the wanted result from data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through your array using `array#map` and regex to convert your string to number.

```js
const data = [{ nutrient: "Energy", per100: "449kcal", per35: "157kcal", id: 6 }, { nutrient: "Fat", per100: "24.4g", per35: "8.6g", id: 1 }, { nutrient: "Saturated fat", per100: "4.5g", per35: "1.6g", id: 2 }, { nutrient: "Monounsaturated fat", per100: "13.6g", per35: "4.8g", id: 3 }],
      result = data.map(o => {
        return Object.keys(o).map(k => {
          if(/\d+/.test(k)) {
            return Number(k.match(/\d+/g));
          }
          return k;
        });
      });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: HI, how would I insert these keys back into the array?

Comment: Do you want to update the key name?

Comment: hi, dont worry im doing it differently now, thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
var data = [
{nutrient: "Energy", per100: "449kcal", per35: "157kcal", id: 6},
 {nutrient: "Fat", per100: "24.4g", "per35": "8.6g", id: 1},
 {nutrient: "Saturated fat", per100: "4.5g", per35: "1.6g", id: 2},
 {nutrient: "Monounsaturated fat", per100: "13.6g", per35: "4.8g", id: 3}
]

var newData = data.map((d) => ({
  nutrient: d.nutrient,
  100: d["per100"],
  35: d["per35"],
  id: d.id
}));

console.log(newData);
```